# Require help to show selected list items in php/html form based on existing MySQL data

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

I am building a php form to update a MySQL database linked to my website.

Part of my form includes list fields where the user can hold ctrl to select multiple values and these are then passed into one MySQL field as comma separated values. See below for three real examples of the data:

3014

3014,3015,3026

3026,3028

The form is updating my database as required, however when the user goes back in to the form to do another update the multiple values they chose aren't pre-selected.

Can anyone help me to figure out why $row_editme['NewsTypeID'] is the field containing the string of values. The field type is a SET.

```
<td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">NewsTypeID:</td>
<td>
  <select name="NewsTypeID[]" size="4" multiple="multiple">
  <?php 
    do {  
  ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $row_types['id']?>" <?php if (!(strcmp($row_types['id'], htmlentities($row_editme['NewsTypeID'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8')))) {echo "SELECTED";} ?>><?php echo $row_types['name']?></option>
  <?php } while ($row_types = mysql_fetch_assoc($types)); ?>
      </select>
</td>
```

Comment: what is in your `$row_editme['NewsTypeID']` ?

Comment: FYI - I have tried writing  {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} instead of {echo "SELECTED";} and this didn't change anything unfortunately.

Comment: Hi Deepak - the $row_editme['NewsTypeID'] contains the selections that the user made as comma separated values so it could contain; 3014,3012,3026 or just 3011 or even 3016,3014 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this,

```
<select name="NewsTypeID[]" size="4" multiple="multiple">
  <?php 
  do {  
    $selected = htmlentities($row_editme['NewsTypeID'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8');
    $selected_arr = explode(",",$selected);
  ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $row_types['id']?>" <?php if (in_array($row_types['id'],$selected_arr)) {echo "selected";} ?>>
      <?php echo $row_types['name']?>
   </option>
  <?php } while ($row_types = mysql_fetch_assoc($types)); ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi Deepak - I think this one is on the right track as it's selecting multiple items. However one strange thing is that it's selecting items that I didn't choose, then it adds one each time I go back in.

Comment: Hi Deepak - thanks so much for your help it's working now. Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not supposed to be selected.

Can you try `checked`?

```
<input type="checkbox" <?php /*if condition is met here, then*/ echo "checked='checked'" ?> />
```

It will pre-select all the values the user selected.

Comment: Unfortunately the checked option didn't work as it's not a series of checkboxes it's a list where you hold down ctrl to select multiple items.

Comment: shucks, I didn't notice. :-) Sorry bout that.